How to create data-frame on RocksDB (SST files)
We hold our documents in RocksDB. We will be syncing these RocksDB sst files to S3. I would like to create a dataframe on the SST files and later run an SQL query. When I googled, I was not able to find any relevant connector for the same.
What is the best way to do this? Can we write a custom dataframe implementation for this? We use Spark 3.1.0 with Scala 2.12
(Converting RocksDB to JSON and to Parquet and then reading dataframe out of Parquet is very time consuming and resource intensive --120 1-core Node minutes. So I can't use this approach.)
[update 1]
Finally I was able to create the dataframe(df) from SST files on Aws s3. I was expecting the performance of this df to be atleast same as the dataframe created on Json files, but it was bad by 4X.
Below is what i couldnt do

implement predicatepushdown. I need this because _id of rockdb is sorted and all joins happenon this _id. I think predicate pushdown will greatly enhance the performance.

code to create dataframe:
    val ss = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
    val rows = //list of sst files from s3
    var javaRdd = ss.sparkContext.parallelize(rows).toJavaRDD()
    javaRdd = javaRdd.flatMap(new KeyValueReader());
    val scalaRdd: RDD[Row] = javaRdd.rdd
    val schemaJson = CloudUtils.getFileAsString(schemaUrl)
    val schema: StructType = DataType.fromJson(schemaJson).asInstanceOf[StructType]
    val df = ss.createDataFrame(scalaRdd, schema)


public class KeyValueReader implements FlatMapFunction<Row, Row> {
 @Override
    public Iterator<Row> call(Row row) throws Exception {
         return new KeyValueIterator(sstFile, schemaUrl);
    }
}

public class KeyValueIterator implements Iterator<Row> {
   public boolean hasNext() {
   }
   public Row next() {
      //download sst file once. get the next row
   }
  
}


You can implement a connector or just write plain Scala code to read the files and create a Dataframe from the files, yes. I've no idea how a SST file is structured but I guess that if you're able to convert it to JSON it should be easily readable to make it a Dataframe. Also note that you could read JSON directly with Spark, no strict need to convert to parquet.

we can read SST using SSTFileReader. Any pointer you can give how to do this?  The spark is reading json and converting them to parquet. This is because the down streams read parquets. We use parquet assuming joins of tables are efficient when we go with parquets (pushdowns)

@GaëlJ -> _id of rockdb are sorted. If we create dataframe direclty from sst files (like with json files) then it may lack predicate pushdown. I need predicate pushdown on _id as we use _id in joins downstream.

If you know how to parse files using plain scala code, you just need spark to distribute it on executors:

List file names in your s3 bucket, It will result in Seq[String]

Transform them to dataset/dataframe (spark.createDataset)

Do mapPartitions operation

Inside mapPartitions, init s3Client, read file content of files using it. Parse using plain scala code, output as case class

Output of mapPratitions will be dataset of parsed files


upd:
that is sample of code
I do not know what is rock db files and how to read them via plain scala code
Assuming you can read them with plain scala, without spark
next code sample can be used to parallelize read/parse with spark
  val session: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(new SparkConf().setMaster("local")).getOrCreate()
  
  import session.implicits._

  def listS3Files(bucket: String, prefix: String): Seq[String] = {
    val s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard.build // add credentials, region if needed
    val listObjectsRequest = (new ListObjectsV2Request)
      .withBucketName(bucket)
      .withPrefix(prefix)
    s3Client.listObjectsV2(listObjectsRequest).getObjectSummaries.asScala.map(_.getKey).filter(p => !p.endsWith("/"))
  }
  
  val bucket = "your-bucket"
  val files = listS3Files(bucket, "test")

  val result = files
    .toDS()
    .mapPartitions(fs => {
      val s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard.build // add credentials, region if needed
      // here got content as string, in your case you need to read rock db files and parse them to case class
      val content = fs.map(f => IOUtils.toString(s3Client.getObject(bucket, f).getObjectContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
      content
    }).cache()


Rocks db indexes all data on _id, in ascending order. Using the above approach would partition pushdown work? Or will the performance be same as creating dataframe on eqvivalent json files?

I am thinking we should implement a dataframe over the SST files. LIke spark gives dataframe on parquet files.

Can you give working example for the above? I am not able to go beyond step 3

@chendu updated with code sample

i think it generates 1 row per file url. But a file may have several rows

@chendu if it has multiple rows use fs.flatMap. It is just an example, how to read files via s3 client. I am not aware what is rocks db file and how to parse it via plain scala code. Provided example is how to distribute any custom file format read via spark.
